# TeXlive2020 TEXMFHOME doesn't exist

Tags: packages, texlive, texstudio, directory, kpsewhich

I am trying to install the "dropping" package from CTAN to compile a template in TeXstudio, using TeXlive2020 on Windows 10. The `dropping.sty` file cannot be found, as the error log in TeXStudio tells me when I try to compile (as well as the fact `kpsewhich dropping.sty` yields nothing even though it works for other .sty files). I copied the extracted file from the CTAN download to `C:\texlive\texmf-local` and I already ran the .ins file in latex. When I use the command `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` I get the expected result `C:/Users/<me>/texmf` but the folder doesn't show up in explorer. I understand you have to make the directory yourself, and comply with the tds structure, so I've tried using the "new folder" icon in the explorer and also using `mkdir tex` with a `latex` folder inside to put the .sty file. I've also tried using `texhash ~/texmf`, however I then get the message "Cannot open ~/texmf/ls-R to write." Despite all this the .sty file refuses to be found and I'm not convinced I went about properly making my TEXMFHOME directory. I don't quite understand how to make the TEXMFHOME directory comply with the tds structure; do I have to add all those random file extensions manually? (I'm referring to something like https://tug.org/tds). I'm fairly green to everything programming related, TeX especially, so I apologize if I used incorrect verbiage. What are my options? All help is appreciated.

P.S. the TexLive documentation suggests creating an environment variable like `TEXINPUTS=.:/my/macro/dir:` to add a personal directory to a search path. Is this what I'm supposed to do? Do I just stick that verbatim in the `../2020/texmf.cnf` file?

Answer (score 4):

By default, TeX Live maintains three distribution subtrees where files for running LaTeX documents are searched for:

1. the main distribution tree, corresponding to the variable `TEXMFDIST`;
2. the local tree, corresponding to `TEXMFLOCAL`;
3. the personal tree, corresponding to `TEXMFHOME`.

The standard value for the second one is `.../texlive/texmf-local` and this is where you put the style file. You should have created the whole structure, that is

```
.../texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/dropping
```

and in this directory place `dropping.sty`.

In your case `...` seems to stand for `C:/texlive`, on my system it's `/usr/local/texlive/2020`.

On a Unix-based system, I'd do

```
mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL)/tex/latex/dropping
```

(with suitable privileges). On Windows there could be a similar way, but you can always look at the output of `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL` and copy-paste it when needed.

Next the task is to run `mktexlsr` (or `texhash`, but the name is deprecated) without options. This is because `TEXMFLOCAL` is searched in by looking at the `ls-R` file.

***Never*** do `mktexlsr ~/texmf`: if a file named `ls-R` is found, the programs only “see” files that are listed there and don't do a recursive lookup.